# Infinite Scroll from Scratch in Reactjs w/ Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, scroll, infinite-scroll

**Background:** I built an infinite scroller using intersection observer for the purpose of re-using dom nodes (aka windowing). When a div scrolls off the top of the viewport it gets absolutely positioned to the end of the sequence of divs, and vice versa for divs that exit the bottom.

**The problem:** If you scroll upward too quickly you scroll past the divs altogether. Meanwhile this doesn't happen if you scroll down too quickly. Having trouble figuring out why.

Codesandbox (original): https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pasteur-wckzm
Codesandbox (updated): https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-scroll-intersection-observer-p15bm

The code (updated):

```
/* eslint no-unused-vars: 0 */
/* eslint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps: 0 */
/* eslint no-sequences: 0 */

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.abc')

    const options = {
      root: null,
      threshold: 0,
      rootMargin: '0px'
    }

    let observer
    if (observer) observer.disconnect()
    observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting || window.pageYOffset === 0) return

        entry.target.onclick = function(){console.log(entry)}
        const firstDiv = entry.target.parentNode.firstElementChild
        const lastDiv = entry.target.parentNode.lastElementChild
        const lastDivTopAmount = Number(lastDiv.style.top.split('').slice(0, -2).join(''))
        const firstDivTopAmount = Number(firstDiv.style.top.split('').slice(0, -2).join(''))

        if (entry.boundingClientRect.top < 0) {
          console.log('element intersected top')
          firstDiv.style.top = `${lastDivTopAmount+320}px`
          firstDiv.parentNode.appendChild(firstDiv)
        }

        else {
          console.log('element intersected bottom')
          lastDiv.style.top = `${firstDivTopAmount-320}px`
          lastDiv.parentNode.prepend(lastDiv)
        }
      })
    }, options)

    divs.forEach(div => {
      observer.observe(div)
    })
}, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="visibleRows">
        <div 
          style={{top: '0px', backgroundColor: 'blue', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-1 abc"
        />
        <div
          style={{top: '320px', backgroundColor: 'red', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-2 abc"
        />
        <div
          style={{top: '640px', backgroundColor: 'green', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-3 abc"
        />
        <div
          style={{top: '960px', backgroundColor: 'purple', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-4 abc"
        />
        <div
          style={{top: '1280px', backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-5 abc"
        />
        <div 
          style={{top: '1600px', backgroundColor: 'pink', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-6 abc"
        />
        <div 
          style={{top: '1920px', backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-7 abc"
        />
        <div 
          style={{top:'2240px', backgroundColor: 'cyan', height: '320px', width: '580px', outline: '4px solid pink'}}
          className="baby-div-8 abc"
        />
      </div>
  </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Styles.css

```
.abc {
  position: absolute;
  height: 320px;
  width: 580px;
  outline: 4px solid pink;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce on a Mac running Chrome. Scrolling down goes forever, scrolling up stops at the top of the current div (at slow and fast speeds). Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @sallf Did you open the demo on codesandbox in full screen? The problem you describe happens if you try and demo the code in the default codesandbox window.

Comment: Yes, I tried in the codesandbox "Browser" window and in the full screen window (https://wckzm.csb.app/). In both cases the result is the same as I described above.

Comment: @salif I forgot to save the css file. Try it now. Working?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the error now. Is the desired result for it to scroll up to infinity, or should it stop when it reaches the top of the page?

Comment: @sallf Desired result is to have the divs rebuilt to their starting point as the user scrolls up, no different than the scroll feed on say twitter. Only time divs should go on for infinite is scrolling downward.

Answer (score 1):

The IntersectionObserver callback is only fired when an observed entry crosses a `threshold`. Since the `threshold` you defined in your options is `0` (and your root is `null`), this means the callback only happens when one of your boxes moves across the `threshold` (aka when a box enters or exits the viewport).

The confusing part is `entries.forEach(...)` **does not loop through all of your observed targets**, it only gets the entities that crossed the threshold.

So your first conditional `if (entry.boundingClientRect.top < 0 && window.pageYOffset > 320) { ... }` works because those conditions can be achieved when your box scrolls off the top of the viewport. However the conditions in your second conditional `if (entry.boundingClientRect.bottom > 1250 && window.pageYOffset > 320) { ... }` will likely never be met because your viewport would need to be `931` high for `bottom > 1250` (`931 + 320 > 1250`).

I'm not quite sure how to get your approach to work with the IntersectionObserver since you can't guarantee a threshold will be crossed when you need it to. It would sort of work if the top box started with a negative `top`, and you just tracked the 'top of the viewport' thresholds...but it would likely get buggy with fast scrolling.

This might be a better job for a [scroll event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)... Or use the Intersection Observer to COPY all the divs once you reach the bottom of your page, as opposed to actually moving them.

**Update**

To try and add further clarity: the second condition will "likely never be met" because on any screen shorter than `931px`, won't have a `boundingClientRect.bottom > 1250` when it "leaves the viewport". In the illustration below, even though the bottom gray box meets that condition, it's not passed as an `entity` when the blue box crosses the `0` threshold.

[image: Intersection Observer entity]

Now, even if you do have a tall enough viewport (or adjusted the number to match the `window.innerHeight`), it still won't work because if you scroll up just enough to move the blue box to the bottom - when scrolling back down no boxes cross your threshold, thus the callback isn't triggered and the blue one doesn't come back up.

[image: Intersection Observer threshold]

Comment: I'm not understanding why the second conditional "will likely never be met". We get an entry whenever a div intersects or leaves the viewport. When a div scrolls off the bottom of the page an entry will be fed to the if statements. At the point it scrolls off the page the .bottom will be greater than the viewport since its past the entire height of the viewport. Doesn't the fact that the second if statement gets met on slow scrolling counter your statement that the 2nd if condition will likely never be satisfied?

Comment: Btw if you check the updated code the second conditional was simply replaced with an else statement. And other cases that don't need to be evaluated are now immedietely returned. Works a bit better, but still bugs out if you scroll up fast enough.

Comment: @RobertC I was a little unsure where your confusion was, so I added two clarifying points. It seems like the first one isn't so helpful after your update, but see if the second one helps. What's the real world application anyways? It's probably worth noting that Interacting with the DOM in this way isn't best practice in React.

Comment: I *think* you're misunderstanding the code in my oldsandbox, but maybe I'm misunderstanding your second point. Not all the entries are intersecting. I specifically feed entries that are already out of the viewport, which is why the two conditionals are wrapped in one that checks for intersecing false. THAT entry is what gets sent to the second conditional. Then it checks if that div already outside the viewport left from the bottom. So in your middle img the blue box triggers the 2nd if, and what gets appended to the top isn't that entry, it's the bottom div of visiblerows.

Comment: That's why I was able to eliminate the second if conditional and make it an else, and why I now immedietely return on intersecting divs. We don't need to check the entry to see if its a certain length from the top, it only needs to be the case that it's not less than 0, and it's outside the viewport (meaning it must've left from the bottom). Which is why it's now an else. If you do some console logs you'll see that the if conditionals only work with divs that are already set to intersecting false, by design.

Comment: Hm, I think I understood the code but maybe missed what problem you were trying to solve. The second iteration definitely works better! Maybe the breaking fast scrolling has something to do with it being async?